# how to combine different process taskbar icon with windows 7

Tags: python, c++, windows, mfc

I want to combine two different procsses taskbar icon which one process was mfc created and the other one process was python created.

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx) ,
I set `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` function by pass the same with parameter GUID `string`  in two different process,but the two process taskbar icon do not combine .

Please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Do the following links help you?

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/article.php/c3227

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-442093.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2d2ef9ad-487b-43d2-997b-e0c2540064d6/

http://www.progtown.com/topic62404-hide-mainframe-from-taskbar.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191/Creating-an-application-with-no-taskbar-icon